# Certificate Revocation List check Failed in IE - Is there a fix in server side?

Tags: security, internet-explorer, nginx, ssl-certificate, ocsp

There is a security alert for my website in Internet Explorer- "Revocation Information for the security certificate for the site is not available...". There are no such errors in Chrome or Firefox. On doing a bit of research, I was able to find out that Chrome/Firefox are using OCSP for checking if the certificate is revoked or not. Also, there is a alternative OCSP stapling that I could configure in my web server.

My Questions are,

1. Why Internet explorer is failing the Certificate Revocation Status check process while the other browsers are succeeding?
2. Is there a fix that we could do in the server to fix this problem in server side for Internet explorer without OCSP feature ?
3. Is this a real vulnerability?

Thanks,
Haleem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why Internet explorer is failing the Certificate Revocation Status check process while the other browsers are succeeding?

by default, web browsers use soft revocation checking failure. If revocation status is `RevocationOffline`, the error is silently skipped. Some browser can be configured to use hard revocation checking failure like you see in Internet Explorer. It is a result of such configuration.

> Is there a fix that we could do in the server to fix this problem in server side for Internet explorer without OCSP feature ?

Internet Explorer uses both, OCSP and CRLs. OCSP stapling is supported in IE as well.

1. If OCSP stapling is presented during TLS handshake, it is used to determine revocation statis.
2. If 1 fails and OCSP URLs are available, OCSP is attempted. If OCSP responds with definitive information, revocation checking ends with responded status.
3. If 1 and 2 failed, then CRL is attempted. If CRL information is reachable and fresh, it is used to determine revocation status. If CRL fails, then `RevocationOffline` error is raised.

Revocation checking may fail at every level, so you may need to make a more thorough investigation. For example, save web server SSL certificate to a `.CER` file and run certutil command:

```
certutil -verify -urlfetch path\sslcert.cer
```

and examine output for errors.

> Is this a real vulnerability?

it depends. The problem here is that you cannot determine whether the presented certificate is revoked by its authority or not. If web site's key is compromised and revoked, you won't notice that and will accept the certificate. I would consider this an issue that needs to be addressed.